# Terraform - App Gateway - Duplicate SSL Certificate Issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a Wildcard SSL Certificate in my KeyVault. I've got multiple hostnames that needs to use the Wildcard SSL Certificate for. I want to create 3x HTTPS Listerners in my Application Gateway, each for the different hostnames (hostname1, hostname2 & hostname3). I can use the same certificate for all 3x HTTPS Listerners if I manually create the Listerners in the Azure Portal but once I try to do it via Terraform, it gives me a duplicate SSL Certificate error.

app_gateway.tf

```
http_listener {
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "AppGWPublicFrontendIP"
    frontend_port_name             = "fp-443"
    host_names                     = ["${var.ENV}.hostname1.company.com"]
    name                           = "fl-hostname-https-443"
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = "star.company.com-cert"
  }
  http_listener {
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "AppGWPublicFrontendIP"
    frontend_port_name             = "fp-443"
    host_names                     = ["${var.ENV}.hostname2.company.com"]
    name                           = "fl-hostname2-https-443"
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = "star.company.com-cert"
  }
  http_listener {
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "AppGWPublicFrontendIP"
    frontend_port_name             = "fp-443"
    host_names                     = ["${var.ENV}.hostname3.company.com"]
    name                           = "fl-hostname3-https-443"
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = "star.company.com-cert"

ssl_certificate {
    name                = "star.company.com-cert"
    key_vault_secret_id = "https://keyvault.vault.azure.net/certificates/star-company-com/${var.certificate_secret_id}"
  }
```

Error:

```
│ Error: updating Application Gateway: (Name "AppGateway_Name" / Resource Group "ResourceGroup_Name"): network.ApplicationGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ApplicationGatewayDuplicateSslCertificate" Message="Application Gateway /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup_Name/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/AppGateway_Name cannot have same certificate used across two Ssl Certificate elements. Certificate for /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup_Name/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/AppGateway_Name/sslCertificates/cert-***-env-hostname-cert and /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup_Name/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/AppGateway_Name/sslCertificates/cert-***-env-hostname-cert are same." Details=[]
```

Comment: In this thread, it looks like it was fixed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193030/terraform-how-to-attach-ssl-certificate-stored-in-azure-keyvault-to-an-applica

Comment: Hi @SoySolisCarlos Yes,it has been resolved. I'll update now.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the specified Application Gateway resource is using a **"duplicate SSL certificate"**.

- *The certificate is shared by two SSL Certificate attributes in the same Application Gateway. The error is also specifying which certificates are similar.*

*To resolve this:*

- ***Make sure that each SSL certificate is only used once in the Application Gateway resource***.

*You can verify the Application Gateway configuration to ensure that the certificates are not being used repeatedly.*

*You can also verify that there are no duplicate SSL certificates in the Azure portal. If there are duplicate certificates, remove it to avoid this kind of conflicts.*

I do agree with @SoySolisCarlos and you can refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221293/19785512) by @Ansuman Bal and I made a few changes to this script by giving my certificate details and it worked as expected.

*Changes in the code:*

```bash
http_listener {
    name                           = listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name = "mycert"
  }
  ssl_certificate {
    name = "mycert"
    key_vault_secret_id = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.main.secret_id
  }
```

*Terraform successfully initialized without any errors:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using a data source:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name = "resource_group_name"
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "KeyVault" {
  name                = "KeyVault_name"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group_name.name
}
data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "star-company-com" {
  name         = "star-company-com"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.KeyVault.id
}

http_listener {
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "AppGWPublicFrontendIP"
    frontend_port_name             = "fp-443"
    host_names                     = ["${var.ENV}.hostname1.company.com"]
    name                           = "fl-hostname-https-443"
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = "star.company.com-cert"
  }

ssl_certificate {
    name                = "star-company-com-cert"
    data                = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.star-company-com.certificate_data
    password            = ""
  }
```